# How to force enchant to use Hunspell in php

Tags: php, spell-checking, hunspell, enchant

Is there a way to force php's enchant module to use a particular spell checking engine?

I have libs for aspell, myspell, hunspell, etc. installed. When requesting a dict, it seems I can only specify a language tag like 'en_US', etc without any real control over which underlying implementation to use while checking. Is there a way I can force enchant to prioritize using hunspell (or any other preferred/supported engine) when spell-checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a `enchant.ordering` file. It is used to tell enchant which spell checker in which sequence to use for a language.
I am using it on ubuntu, the path of the file is `/usr/local/share/enchant/enchant.ordering`
I don't know for windows.